# How can I find and print all existed window titles using Radrails?

Tags: window, watir

I use watir in radrails IDE.
How can I find and print all existing window titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only been able to get all windows using win32ole. Note that this only works for IE (which I assume you are using since the question's tag is watir not watir-webdriver).

The following is an example of outputting all titles:

```
require 'win32ole'
WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application').Windows.each do |window|
    if window.path =~ /Internet Explorer/
        puts window.Document.Title
    end
end
```